# Access textbox value from within featherlight lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, featherlight.js

I am trying to use featherlight lightbox to ask for a user's input in a text-box. However, I see that the text-box value (when accessed via javascript after being changed by end-user) always returns default value. Details below:

My lightbox div HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" value="Sample" />
<a href="#" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('mytextbox').value);">Show TextBox Val</a>
</div>
```

When I click the 'Show TextBox Val' link after changing the text-box value, the alert always shows the value as 'Sample' (the default value).

When I try using the above div outside the lightbox (as a normal div), it functions well.

- How do we access changed textbox value on link/ button click?
- Why is it always displaying the default value despite the current value having being changed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use the `persist` option, featherlight clones the content. Since you're using an ID, that's a no-no.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the value from the text-box using ID after setting persist to true and now understand why wasn't getting it earlier. What would be the right way to get value (other than using ID) if I could not keep persist to true?

Comment: Let me get this right. How do i prevent featherlight from cloning?. If i use persist: true  => will it not clone and show the actual div?. thank you.